# Do we need to review accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22553488

The OP answered his question himself. Even if the answer was from somebody else, I think "no action needed" is the only option for this answer, because the OP already marked it as helpful, right?

So, the question is, can accepted answers be removed from review queues?

Comment: Why should these be removed from the review queues? I don't understand what's your point. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Reviewing them doesn't have any effect, because as I said, "no action needed" is the only option for them.

Comment: Suppose the self-accepted-answer says: *I found the solution, thanks everyone*. Why shouldn't we delete that?

Comment: But why do we need to review them? Are there any cases when you will flag accepted answer? Downvote? Leave a comment?

Comment: Oh, I have down voted, flagged and deleted plenty of accepted answers. So, yes please let the reviewers have a stake in that.

Comment: "No Action Needed" was emphatically the wrong call there. At a *minimum*, it should have been edited.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, self-answers by new users should continue appearing in review queues. They are significantly more likely than average to need attention:

- OP may have been trying to post additional information, which should be in an edit to the question, not in an answer. This sort of thing is reasonably common
- The answer may not be well formatted, or well-explained - the former you can edit to fix, the latter you can comment on to prompt the OP to elaborate
- If it's a good answer, it's good to give the new user positive feedback with an upvote
- Similarly, if it's a bad answer (or not an answer at all), the reverse applies - one may downvote, comment to explain the problem(s) with it, and possibly flag it.

These are all *useful actions* that one may take that help new users learn how the site works, and they are all applicable even when the answer in question is OP's answer to his own question.

Comment: Good point. I stumbled upon a self "non-answer" *from 2010* last week. Apparently the question had received little attention, so the OP posted an "answer" that simply contained more details about the question, and nobody cared enough to do anything about it for years.